# Display data from two or more models (with same data structure) in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

We are building an application with Active Admin and Rails. It has a series of models that all have the same data structure.

We'd now like a view that displays all the data from these models together in the one table.

The reason for the separation into many models is it all comes from different sources.

So as an administrator I would like to view all the data together.

This data is read only so there is no need to write.

Using the below code, I am able to render all the data together with a custom page, however this does not leverage the ActiveAdmin built in table rendering, so it is pointless. Please see screenshot below and the code used.

[image: Screenshot of current code]

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Top Sellers" do
    content do
        table_for @items = Dingoat.all + Dingobe.all do
            column "Product Name", :ProductName
            column "Start Date", :StartDate
            column "End Date", :EndDate
        end

    end

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is using the ActiveAdmin table component. The only thing missing is to wrap it in a panel:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Top Sellers" do
  content do
    panel "Sellers" do
      table_for(Dingoat.all + Dingobe.all) do
        column "Product Name", :ProductName
        column "Start Date", :StartDate
        column "End Date", :EndDate
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Or you could style it to look like the index pages:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Top Sellers" do
  content do
    # Note the addition of index_table class.
    table_for(Dingoat.all + Dingobe.all, class: 'index_table') do
      column "Product Name", :ProductName
      column "Start Date", :StartDate
      column "End Date", :EndDate
    end
  end
end
```